# Re-Indent in TeXShop

Tags: indentation, texshop, sourcecode

Is there something as Re-Indent (in Xcode) or Smart Indent (in Matlab) for TeXShop?

Comment: Could you rephrase the question to make it clearer what you would like to do. For those of us not familiar with Xcode this is pretty hard to understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no way to do this in TeXShop. It's probably the one major failing of it as an editor. You can select portions of text and indent them but since TeXShop soft-wraps lines, this doesn't always do what you want it to do.  The code is open-source, and new additions are always welcome, though.